# Universe flatness

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, curvature, geodesics

On: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_of_the_universe

It is written:

> "The exact shape is still a matter of debate in physical cosmology, but experimental data from various independent sources (WMAP, BOOMERanG, and Planck for example) confirm that the universe is flat with only a 0.4% margin of error. On the other hand, any non-zero curvature is possible for a sufficiently large curved universe (analogously to how a small portion of a sphere can look flat)."

1. I'm not really sure what it means: doesn't light bend near the sun (masses in general)?
2. It's just the point of view that makes we see the light bending?
3. Flatness means that general relativity doesn't work in an absolute way?
4. General relativity is just a way of watching the universe: in order to see a curved line straight we see the sraight lines curved?

Comment: The [reason](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/10344/what-is-a-friedmann-model) it's called flat is that the geometry is like that of a flat 2D table, only in 3D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch of caveats to the statement about flatness, but to answer your questions:

1. This is talking about the overall, large-scale curvature of the cosmology, zoomed out so far that whole galaxies are points.  Any curvature due to objects like the sun is too small to matter on this scale.
2. In general relativity, the fact that light rays bend is not a point of view thing.  The presence of curvature is locally measurable
3. The flatness being discussed here is, again, an averaged out comsological flatness.  It's also worth saying that it is not the flatness of spacetime, but rather just of the three-dimensional spatial sections.  The spacetime is still curved.
4. I don't understand what this means, but the point is that geodesics are not straight lines, they are the closest thing possible to a straight line in a curved geometry.  Just like how you could tell that you're not travelling in a straight line while moving on the globe, you can tell that your geodesic is not straight (at least when you compare it to nearby geodesics)